# How to access RabbitMQ service (on host machine) from Spring boot docker container running on same machine

Tags: spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

Environment Details

> Windows 10
>
> Docker Desktop
>
> Spring Boot ( Using it inside Container)
>
> RabbitMQ ( Installed on my windows machine as a Service)

I would like to access RabbitMQ service from the Spring Boot Container.
I provided below properties inside application.properties

```
batch.rabbitmq.host=localhost
batch.rabbitmq.port=5672
batch.rabbitmq.username=guest
batch.rabbitmq.password=guest
server.port=8083
```

I am running my spring boot app as

> docker run -p 8083:8083 dockerdemo

I can access the RabbitMQ management console using localhost:15672
but my spring boot application unable to connect it.

It throw connection

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

What do I need to change, Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside the container localhost is resolved to inside the container not the physical host machine. So you need to change the setting to something like this

```
batch.rabbitmq.host=[HOST_NAME OR IP Address]
```

Comment: Will it work for SQL server URL also? 
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<HOST_NAME>;databaseName=abc

Comment: Yes...anytime you mention localhost inside the container , the connection to restricted to the ports inside the container. So even in this case you need to mention the host name or IP

Comment: Thanks Soumen, I tried your solution, but it seems my spring boot app started and stopped immediately. i am unable to see my log files. Basically,dont know where to see logs in container.

Comment: I tried and found that The TCP/IP connection to the host <MY_HOST>, port 1433 has failed.
It is working outside container. Inbound rule is also set in windows firewall.

Comment: Possibly it is not able to resolve the host name , did you try with IP